# How to access the parentNode of a selection to raise an element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created the following document:

```
<g>
    <path class=​"line" name=​"gene_1" stroke=​"#aec7e8" d=​"M10.47...">​</path>​
    <path class=​"line" name=​"gene_2" stroke=​"#aec7e8" d=​"M10.47...">​</path>​
    <path class=​"line" name=​"gene_3" stroke=​"#aec7e8" d=​"M10.47...">​</path>​
    ...
</g>
```

When I mouse over each path I want to append it last inside the `svg:g` so it appears on top of the other lines, but I don't know how to properly select the `parentNode`:

```
function onmouseover(d, i){
  var current_gene_name = d3.select(this).attr("name"),
      current_gene_pcp = d3.select(".line[name=" + current_gene_name + "]");

  p1 = this.parentNode 

  p2 = current_gene_pcp[0].parentNode

  p3 = current_gene_pcp[0][0].parentNode

  //p.appendChild(this);
}
```

`p1` works, but I wanted to make sure that `this` is a `.line`, so I preferred to use `current_gene_pcp`, but `p2` returns `<html></html>` as the parent, even though `p3` returns the proper `<g></g>`. This last version seems like a bug waiting to happen. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A D3 selection is just a double-array wrapped around the element(s) selected. As you found with `p3`, you can dereference the arrays to find your first node, if you want. However, a better method does exist:

From the docs for [`selection.node()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-node):

> *Returns the first non-`null` element in the current selection. If the selection is empty, returns `null`.*

In your case:

```js
var dad = current_gene_pcp.node().parentNode;
```

However, if you don't need the line other than the DOM handle, you might as well just get that directly:

```
// Search document-wide...
var dad = document.querySelector(".line[name=" + current_gene_name + "]");

// ...or only as a child of the current DOM element
var dad = this.querySelector(".line[name=" + current_gene_name + "]");
```

Answer (score 36):

Here's a quick way to move the mouseover element to the front:

```
selection.on("mouseover", function() { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); });
```

See also a [related thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/eUEJWSSWDRY/EMmufH2KP8MJ) in the d3-js group.

Comment: This behavior is unstable. When I try this in Chrome in combination with `:hover` styles, the styles are correctly applied. When I try this in Firefox (v20), the styles are not applied at all. When I remove this `mouseover` code, the styles are correctly applied in Firefox. I guess this is caused by an element's mouseover` trying to remove itself before it's reattached as the last child of its DOM.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to access it.
Either use the [third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437116/third-variable-in-d3-anonymous-function) like this: `someNode.attr("someAttrib", function(d, i, j) { console.log(d, i, j); });`. The `j` contains the data you supplied to the parent node.
or use `d3.select(this.parentNode).data()[0].id;`.

An example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="area", width="1000px" height="1000px"></div>
<script>
var GAP = 10, NODE_RADIUS = 14;

  var nodes = [
    {id: 1, prop: [{id: 1, something: 1}], abc: 1},
    {id: 2, prop: [{id: 1, something: 1}, {id: 2, something: 1}, {id: 3, something: 1}], abc: 2},
    {id: 3, prop: [{id: 1, something: 1}, {id: 2, something: 1}], abc: 3},
    {id: 4, prop: [{id: 1, something: 1}], abc: 4},
    {id: 5, prop: [{id: 1, something: 1}], abc: 5},
    {id: 6, prop: [], abc: 6}
  ];

var nodeLayer = d3.select("#area").selectAll(".node").data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id; });
var iNodes = nodeLayer.enter().append("svg").attr("class", "node");
    //append the black circle
    iNodes.append("circle")
                .style("fill", "black")
                .attr("r", NODE_RADIUS)
                .attr("cx", function(d) {return 10 + d.id * 10;})
                .attr("cy", 100);

    iNodes.append("g").selectAll(".prop").data(function(d) {return d.prop;}).enter()
            .append("text")
                .text(function(d,i,j){console.log("parent id="+j); return d3.select(this.parentNode).data()[0].id;})
                .attr("dx", 50)
                .attr("dy", 50)
                .style("font-size", "8px")
                .style("fill", d3.rgb(180,0,0))
                .style("text-anchor", "middle");

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I had to go up 2x levels: `console.log(">>"+my_chart.node().parentNode.parentNode.id+"<<")`

Answer (score 0):

One way I have done is:

```
bars.on('mouseover', d => {
let parentNode = d3.select(this.parentNode);
let tooltip = parentNode.append('rect)
```

from `this` key word, you can access the current node, then touch its parentNode.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of D3 [v4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-40) this has become an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) of sorts. There is no longer the need to get to the `parentNode` to re-insert elements as the last child of its parent. Because from that release on D3 offers the [`selection.raise()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_raise) method:

> *selection*.**raise**()
>
> Re-inserts each selected element, in order, as the last child of its parent. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> selection.each(function() {
>   this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
> });
> ```

Using D3 **v6** where the event is passed as the first parameter to the event listener (see [changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#d3-selection)) your code can be as simple as this:

```
function onmouseover(event) {
  d3.select(event.target).raise();
}
```

Have a look at the following demo:

```js
d3.select("g")
  .on("mouseover", event => d3.select(event.target).raise())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="400">
  <g>
    <rect x="100" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
    <rect x="150" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="blue"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```